# Magento placing order error

Tags: magento, orders

I have problem with Magento Enterprise ver. 1.10.1.1

All new products have problem what placing order. Javascript popup with this error is showing:
"There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later."

Older products are working fine.

Magento debug error for placing order is:

```
DEBUG (7): Create Order Response: stdClass Object
(
    [CreateOrderResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errorCode] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => VALIDATION
                    [message] => product_variant_id is required.  Procedure or function 'rwGetProductVariantBySKU' expects parameter '@SKUSuffix', which was not supplied.
                )

        )

)
```

What is product variant id?
Do you have a clue?

Comment: dude you have enterprise :) contact EE support for this :)

Answer (score 0):

often, variant means assigned simple product to some configurable.

In your case error really strange, looks like problem located in some custom module
"rwGetProductVariantBySKU" -- this is not native method. So you need to search in app/* directory this string "rwGetProductVariantBySKU" and then debug what exactly happens, who calls this method etc.

Hope it will help.